# Algebra is stable under finite unions, $\sigma$-algebra under countable, what about uncountable?

Tags: measure-theory

Per definition the Algebra is stable under finite unions and a $\sigma$-algebra is stable under countable unions.

Is there a similar structure with stability over any union of subsets (including uncountable)? Or does this not make sense for some reason?

Comment: A topology? ${}$

Comment: Ah yes, thank you. Make it an answer =)